# how do I format datetimepicker values properly in ISO 8601 Format

Tags: google-calendar-api, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm kinda stuck here while adding events in google calendar, everything so far has gone in right way except this, when I am inserting a new event using datetimepicker for date and time the google calendar displaying me wrong date and time for the event.

Since, Google Calendar uses ISO 8601 Format so I guess if I can able to convert the date and time I'm getting into ISO 8601 format then my problem would be resolved. Need help from you guys.. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, finally got my answer my own and it's quite easy to convert just few line of code.

```
$tzname=$_POST['tzname'];    
$endDate = strtotime($endDate);
$dt= new DateTime("@$endDate");
$googleEventTime = new DateTimeZone($tzname);
$googleendevent=$dt->format('c');
```

then you pass this   `$googleendevent` into google calendar event array. :)